# Extend Office JavaScript API with own Browser Control

Tags: vsto, webbrowser-control, office-js

I'm trying to write a VSTO-Add-In with a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser-Control enabling something similar to the Office-JS-Add-In model.

The WebBrowser-control would show some HTML/JS-Page and be able to call C#-functions in the VSTO-Add-In from JavaScript via window.external and the ObjectForScripting-property of the WebBrowser-object.

That is in JS the call would be

```
window.external.DoFancyStuffToMyDocument(withTheseParams)
```

while there had to be some

```
class MyFunctionProxy() {
    public void DoFancyStuffToMyDocument(string theParam) {
        //code here
    }
}
```

in the C#-Code an this would be attached to the WebBrowser

```
myWebBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new MyFunctionProxy();
```

So far so good. Now comes the catch. I want my HTML/JS-Code be able to also utilize the office.js code and functions like

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var thisDocument = context.document;
    var range = thisDocument.getSelection();
    range.insertText('"Hitch your wagon to a star."\n', Word.InsertLocation.replace);
    //...
}
```

Does anyone see a way of getting this to work?

My initial guess was that the OfficeJS-taskpane-add-ins in Word on-prem use some some similar methode as above with a class derived from WebBrowser and the appropriate ObjectForScripting. This would then suggest that there must be a (hopefully accessible) class which is assigned to the ObjectForScripting-property handling the function calls from office.js. Then I could proxy this ObjectForScripting-class and add my own functions like 'DoFancyStuffToMyDocument()'.

Comment: What is the purpose of such solutions? Isn't it better to implement the required functionality in a VSTO based add-in instead of JS?

Comment: Good question! I looked into this before and didn't get anywhere. @EugeneAstafiev I can see it helping in transitioning an existing addin from VSTO to officejs - ie. develop all new functionality in officejs and include it in your current VSTO addin. On a side note (and even less likely), it would be great to use a Chrome wrap for officejs solutions on Word Desktop - IE/Edge is soooooo slow and need so much "polyfiller".

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Let me write this comment again, as typing from my phone really messed it up: It is a requirement by the customer. The only want to roll out a single VSTO-AddIn (with all the necessary special functions like DoFancyStuffToMyDocument(), see above) and then have an easier way to distribute the HTML/JS-Files in their environment.

Comment: Hosting a web browser control inside Office applications will lead to other issues. So, I'd recommend choosing another strategy and create a simple VSTO add-in.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Could you please elaborate on the possible problems of hosting the WebBrowser-control inside Office applications. On a first quick PoC it seemed to work well.

Comment: Mostly you may face with various focusing issues - keyboard shortcuts stop working correctly, cursor disappearing and etc.